# Django model fields

Tags: django

Ok, so I would like some advice on how to set up a model. I have a recipe model I'm developing (plan on putting a tablet in the kitchen). What I would like to be able to do is have each recipe have an ingredients list, but also have a corresponding quantity list that matches up to the ingredient list. The idea is that I have an Ingredient model that will be used to keep track of what ingredients I have on hand and how much, and the Recipe model will have it's own ingredients list as well as what quantities are needed. That way I could have the app show recipes that I have ingredients to make, and hide ones I don't have ingredients to (or actually it will be more elaborate but that's the idea). Here's my current setup:

Ingredient model.py

```
class Unit_of_Measure(models.Model):

   """Unit_of_Measure model. This is used as the foriegnkey for the Quantity model unit_of_measure key."""

   class Meta:
           verbose_name_plural = "Units of Measure"

   def __unicode__(self):
           return self.unit_of_measure

   unit_of_measure = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Location(models.Model):

   """Location model. This is used a the foriegnkey for the Ingredient model location key."""

   class Meta:
           verbose_name_plural = "Locations"

   def __unicode__(self):
           return self.place

   place = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Ingredient(models.Model):

   """Ingredients model. Includes ingredient title, quantity on hand, location of ingredient (foreignkey), expiration date, and if it is a shop for ingrdient."""

   class Meta:
           verbose_name_plural = "Ingredients"

   def __unicode__(self):
           return self.title

   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   unit_of_measure = models.ForeignKey(Unit_of_Measure)
   location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
   expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()
   shop_for = models.BooleanField()
```

Recipe model.py

```
class RecipeType(models.Model):

   """Recipe type model. This is used as the foreign key for the Recipe model recipe style."""

   def __unicode__(self):
           return self.style

   style = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Recipe(models.Model):

   """Recipe model. Includes recipe title, recipe style (dinner, snack, etc..), ingredient list (foreignkey), recipe instructions, storage style, and expiration date."""

   class Meta:
           verbose_name_plural = "Recipes"

   def __unicode__(self):
           return self.title

   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   style = models.ForeignKey(RecipeType)
   required_ingredient_list = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, related_name='additional_ingredient_list')
   additional_ingredient_list = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, related_name='required_ingredient_list', blank=True)
   recipe_instruction = models.TextField()
   storage_style = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

So any suggestion as to how to match up two field lists? like "required_ingredient_list" matching up to "required_ingredient_quantity_list" or something? Or a better solution? Or any suggestions in general? Right now I can sort recipes by ingredients but since the Ingredient model's quantity is quantity I have on hand in my kitchen, I don't really have a field to represent the quantities the recipe uses, it just gets said in the recipe_instruction field. Halpz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ["through model"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to link Recipes to Ingredients. The intermediate model could then have an associated unit and a numeric or string measure associated with that.

Comment: huh. I added a RecipeIngredient model after Recipe as a through model, but nothing shows on the admin page (models.Recipe added field "ingredient_list = models.ManyToManyField('ingredient.Ingredient', through='recipe.RecipeIngredient'") noooothing shows on admin page for ingredient_list. any ideas?

Comment: nevermind! i got it, just had to add the RecipeIngredient model to the RecipeAdmin as an inline. now it displays the recipe ingredients on the recipe page as an inline. sweet.